# Solving class coupling between Point() and Vector()

Tags: c++

I have two classes and I would like to preserve the associated mathematical abstractions.

The class Point is defined in Point.h:

```
// Point.h
class Vector; // Forward declaration

// #include "Vector.h" // Error: redundant include

class Point
{
 /* Constructors and standard stuff */

 Vector normal{}; // Compiler error: Vector is not defined at this point, only declared.
 Point getDest(Vector & v, double distance);
}
```

And Vector.h

```
#include "Point.h"

class Vector
{
/* Constructors and standard stuff */

void calcVector(const Point * p1, const Point * p2)
{
    this->setX(p2->getX() - p1->getX());
    this->setY(p2->getY() - p1->getY());
    this->setZ(p2->getZ() - p1->getZ());
}
}
```

As you can see, I need the complete definition of the class Point in order to implement `calcVector()`

I would like to have a Vector type attribute inside of the `Point` class as shown in the snippet, but in order to do that, I need to let the compiler know the complete definition of `Vector` when compiling, yielding to a circular include problem when including the `Vector.h` in `Point.h`.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: It looks like `Vector` deals in `Point*`. forward declare `class Point;` and forego the include.

Comment: Do you *really* want to mention `Vector` inside your `Point.h`?  It seems like adding a `static Vector normal(Point p);` method to your `Vector` class, instead, would avoid the problem.

Comment: As much as calculus professors love to espouse the difference between vectors and points, I've never seen a convincing argument for distinguishing the two in code. They're both ordered tuples of numbers, which we can add, scalar multiply, etc., etc. The public interfaces are identical.

Comment: Since when does a point contain a vector of points (kind of circular)?  IMHO, a point **has-a** coordinates, like x, y, z.  A math vector has a magnitude, direction and maybe starting point.  Did I miss something?